# Resource Cannot Be Found Error on Using "HttpPost" in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hello
 Am Working on a ASP.Net MVC 3 project and am getting a error called "Resource cannot be found" My situation is i have 
 1: am Using my own views and returning them in actions for instance i created a view manually first called "Create.cshtml" and manually added it to a action like this

```
[HttpPost]
 Public ActionResult CreateStudent(StudentIfo studentinfo)
{
 db.StudentInfo.add(studentinfo);
 db.SaveChanges();
Return View("~/Views/Student/Create.cshtml");
}
```

[HttpGet] Before this Action works good but why Not HttpPost???

My Route Map says:

```
routes.MapRoute(" ",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Student", action = "CreateStudent", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

2: Whenever i write [HttpPost] i get this Error and if I remove it then everything works good if such thing continues then how to save the data??

3: My Create.cshtml has a `@Html.BeginForm("CreateStudent","Student",FormMethod.Post)` am not getting what the issue is?? i have searched a lot but not getting a good answer.

4: What is best way for CURD operation when we are using our own views rather using Visual studios Scaffolding templates i.e am I going in right way?? i want my own views and then write my controllers according to them not as that of Visual Studio way first write  controller then right click "Add-View"

Please recommend some good ways or any site or tutorials regarding it.

Comment: please read: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Thanks @tereško  for your Link but As am new to this forum stuff i was unaware of that formatting thank you

Comment: No problem.  Remember, when you decorate with [HttpPost] - that method will only be called when you POST to it (ajax request with method: post or a form submission).  You will not be able to access it by typing that path in your browser.  That is a GET request.

Answer (score 2):

In short you will need both, you need a [HttpGet] action to return the initial form that the user can enter values into and then a [HttpPost] version to do the persistence. From this [HttpPost] method you should then RedirectToAction (return RedirectToAction(...)) to ensure that reloading of the page does not re-run the post operation.

So:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateStudent()
{
    var viewModel = new CreateStudentViewModel { /* Set properties here or load data for it */ };
    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateStudent(PostedValues values)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Create Student Here
        return RedirectToAction(/* Jump to a logical place with a Get */)
    }

    /* Initialize correct error viewModel again and show the create student screen with validation errors */
    return View(viewModel)
}
```

Personally I name these methods GetCreateStudent and PostCreateStudent and add two routes with a route constraint that limits the Http Method (see [here](http://archive.arcware.net/2009/02/27/adding-httpmethodconstraint-to-asp-net-mvc-routes/))